# Xcode: Any way to change how hot-key comments are formatted?

Tags: swift, xcode, code-formatting

Right now, if you hit CMD + /, the current or selected line(s) of code is(are) prepended with "//" turning it into a comment. No surprises.

However, it always puts the "//" at the very beginning of the line and not at the beginning of the text.

If you've got indented code, you might end up with a line that looks like:

```
//                               let x = "MyCommentedOutLineOfCode"
```

What I want is:

```
                               // let x = "MyCommentedOutLineOfCode"
```

I can't seem to find a way to change that. Anyone know how to do that?

I know, it's a silly thing, but when you later auto-format code, it makes a mess.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option, but I know the problem ;) Let's try to make Apple change it. Of course you can always just type 2x "/" yourself

Comment: Why not write a plug-in that does it as you prefer?

Comment: Mostly because I'm a paid-to-code guy working two jobs and taking the time to do so just feels like a bridge too far. :)